# Creation of a project in visual c++express edition

Tags: visual-c++-2008-express

In Visual Studio Express 2008 edition there are many types of projects listed under the Visual C++ heading, such as CLR, WIN32, GENERAL.. From these, which one is most appropriate for my purposes?

I'm looking to write a C program.

I want to interface my programs with an lcd simulator. Instead of seeing the output on dos prompt, i want see my output on lcd, so i have used functions lij ginit(), which help for interfacing with lcd. But the question is , which type of project should I select, which will make it convenient for me to interface with lcd????

Answer (score 0):

The project types listed there are just templates that presets settings to a specific need.  If you select a template, you will see a description telling you what its used for.  Since you don't need Windows or console interface, go with an Empty Project on the General tab.